# Constructing std::function argument from lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, stl, template-argument-deduction

I have the following templated function (C++ latest standard is enabled in the compiler - but maybe 17 would be enough).

```
#include <functional>

template<typename TReturn, typename ...TArgs>
void MyFunction(const std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)>& callback);

int main()
{
    MyFunction(std::function([](int){}));
    MyFunction([](int){});
}
```

The first call compiles, when I explicitly convert it to std::function, but the second case does not.

In the first case the template deduction is done automatically, the compiler only knows that it shall convert it to some std::function and able to deduce the parameter and return type.

However in the second case it shall(?) also know that the lambda shall be converted to some std::function, but still unable to do it.

Is there a solution to get the second one running? Or can it be that for templates the automatic conversion does not take place at all?

The error message is:

> error C2672: 'MyFunction': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2784: 'void MyFunction(const std::function<_Ret(_Types...)> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::function<_Ret(_Types...)>
>
> note: see declaration of 'MyFunction'

What I am aiming for is a "python style decorator". So basically this:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename ...TArgs>
auto MyFunction(std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)>&& callback) -> std::function<TReturn(TArgs...)>
{
     return [callback = std::move(callback)](TArgs... args)->TReturn
     {
          return callback(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    };
}
```

If I used a template instead of std::function, the how would I deduce the parameter pack and return value? Is there some way to get it from a callable via some "callable traits"?

Comment: What errors do you get? Please edit your question to include them (in full and complete).

Comment: And depending on use-case and design, you might be able to bypass this problem by using a single template type for the callable object itself, as in `template<typename F> void MyFunction(F callback);`

Comment: Side note, don't use std:: function with templates, make the lambda type the template argument and constrain it via std::is_invokable (when relevant)

Comment: Thank you all. See my updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or can it be that for templates the automatic conversion does not take place at all?

Yes. Implicit conversions won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

That means given `MyFunction([](int){});`, the implicit conversion (from lambda to `std::function`) won't be considered, then the deduction for `TReturn` and `TArgs` fails and the invocation attempt fails too.

As the workarounds, you can

1. Use explicit conversion as you showed
2. As [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664303/constructing-stdfunction-argument-from-lambda/54664400#comment96119097_54664303) suggested, just use a single template parameter for functors. e.g.

   ```
   template<typename F>
   auto MyFunction2(F&& callback)
   {
        return [callback = std::move(callback)](auto&&... args)
        {
             return callback(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
   }
   ```

Comment: I have edited my question to be a bit more specific, what I am aiming for

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from lambda to `std::function`, is there? However, there is implicit conversion of non-capturing lambda to a function pointer, which in turn can be used to initialize the `std::function`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak std::function has a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) (the 5th one) for it.

Comment: @songyuanyao, I should not post comments before finishing my first coffee. How did I miss constructing `std::function` from a callable object (which lambda is), which I used many times, and instead thought only of construction through function pointer?

Comment: It works now, thanks. JVAPen suggested to check the type with std::is:invocablem but static_assert(std::is_invocable<TCallback>::value, "Wrapped object must be invocable"); always give false and the assert fails