# Infering template type from function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-inference

I'm not sure about the title of the question, but basically I'm curious of how to create a visitor-like function that can operate on certain types on a collection that correctly uses type inference.

For example, a collection contains objects that inherit from a single base class (`Base`). Some operations apply only to specific child classes (e.g., `FooBar` inherits from `Base`).

One implementation can be

```
template<class T, class F>
void visit(F f)
{
  for (auto c : the_collection) {
    if (auto t = dynamic_cast<T*>(c)) {
      f(t);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that invoking such function will need to specify the class type `FooBar` twice:

```
visit<FooBar>([](FooBar* f) { f->some_method(); });
```

I'd like to use type inference, so I can just write `visit([](FooBar* f) ...`, but can't manage to get the right template.

For example:

```
template<class T>
using Visitor = std::function<void(T*)>;
template<class T>
void visit(const Visitor<T>& f)
{
  for (auto c : the_collection)
    if (auto t = dynamic_cast<T*>(c))
      f(t);
}
```

works with `visit<FooBar>([](FooBar*) ...` but not with `visit([](FooBar*) ...`.

> no matching overloaded function found
>
> void visit(const std::function<void(T *)> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::function<void(T *)> &' from '{....}::<lambda_2c65d4ec74cfd95c8691dac5ede9644d>

Is it possible to define a template that can infer the types in this way or the language specification doesn't allow to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructing std::function argument from lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664303/constructing-stdfunction-argument-from-lambda). You also might wanna have a look at the numerous other questions on exactly the same problem, e.g., this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784120/how-to-define-template-parameters-for-a-generic-lambda-argument ;)

Comment: Why not use regular visitor pattern if you have polymorphic class already?

Comment: upcasting almost always means trouble and design flaws, but I'm sure you absolutely know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged C++17 so you can use deduction guides for `std::function`.

So what about something as follows ?

```
template <typename>
struct first_arg_type;

template <typename R, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct first_arg_type<std::function<R(T0, Ts...)>>
 { using type = T0; };

template <typename F>
void visit (F const & f)
 {
   using T = typename first_arg_type<decltype(std::function{f})>::type;

   for (auto c : the_collection)
      if (auto t = dynamic_cast<T>(c))
         f(t);
 }
```

Observe that, instead of the custom type trait `first_arg_type` you could use the standard type `first_argument_type` in `std::function`, so

```
   using T = typename decltype(std::function{f})::first_argument_type;
```

Unfortunately `std::function::first_argument_type` is deprecated starting from C++17 and will be removed from C++20.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found to do this so far (but not exactly what I've been looking for) is to define the visitor using the second form indicated in the question, and to declare the lambda parameter as `auto`:

```
template<class T>
using Visitor = std::function<void(T*)>;
template<class T>
void visit(const Visitor<T>& f)
{
  for (auto c : the_collection)
    if (auto t = dynamic_cast<T*>(c))
      f(t);
}

// ...

visit<FooBar>([](auto f) { f->some_method(); });
```

Comment: `template<class T, typename F> void visit(F&& f)` would avoid unneeded `std::function` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the desired syntax of `visit([](FooBar*){ /*...*/ });` by deducing the type of the call operator of the lambda.

```
template <typename Element, typename Class, typename Parameter>
void call(Element element, Class *callable, void(Class::*function)(Parameter) const) {
  if (auto parameter = dynamic_cast<Parameter>(element)) {
    (callable->function)(parameter);
  }
}

template <typename Functor>
void visit(Functor &&functor) {
  for (auto element : the_collection) {
    call(element, &functor, &Functor::operator());
  }
}
```