# How can I make C++ infer template type parameters from a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, type-inference

This is my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

struct Item {
  int val;
};

struct XItem {
  int val;
};

void transform(const Item &i, XItem &target) {
  target.val = i.val;
}

template<typename T>
void show(const T &v) {
  std::cout << v.val << std::endl;
}

template<typename ParamsType, typename ResultType>
void handleRequest(Item &cur, ResultType (*impl)(const ParamsType &p)) {
  ParamsType p{};
  transform(cur, p);
  ResultType res = (*impl)(p);
  show(res);
}

struct ResItem {
  int val;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Item i{42};
  handleRequest(i, [](const XItem &x) {
    return ResItem{x.val};
  });
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it gives the following error:

```
test.cpp:33:3: error: no matching function for call to 'handleRequest'
  handleRequest(i, [](const XItem &x) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:21:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'ResultType
      (*)(const ParamsType &)' against '(lambda at test.cpp:33:20)'
void handleRequest(Item &cur, ResultType (*impl)(const ParamsType &p)) {
     ^
```

I am unsure why this happens, however I do suspect that because the lambda, while being *implicitly convertible* to a function pointer, isn't one, the template parameters can't be deduced from it.

I tried using `std::function<ResultType(const ParamsType &p)>` instead, which also doesn't work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664303/constructing-stdfunction-argument-from-lambda) details the problem, so I tried to use its solution:

```cpp
template<typename ParamsType, typename ResultType, typename Callback>
void handleRequest(Item &cur, Callback cb) {
  ParamsType p = transform(cur);
  ResultType res = std::invoke(cb, p);
  show(res);
}
```

However, now `ParamsType` and `ResultType` cannot be implicitly deduced from the callback, I would need to give them explicitly. But I really want to infer `ResultType` because in the actual code, it can be quite lengthy (it is inferred from the lambda `return` statement, which is more complex than in this minimal example). I need the two types because both `transform` and `show` are overloaded and need the types to bind.

Is it possible to have `handleRequest` infer those types in this scenario and if so, how?

Comment: What about `auto p = transform(cur); auto res = cb(p);`?

Comment: If you need the types in the context of the function you can additionally use `decltype`

Comment: @super In actual code, I would have multiple transforms like `A transform(const Item&) {…}`, `B transform(const Item&) {…}` which would be illegal.

Comment: In that case extracting the types with a type-trait is the more idiomatic approch. Keeps the code more generic then requiring a function pointer to be passed. Especially since that limits you to lambdas without capture.

Comment: @super Mind that the body of `handleRequest` is vastly simplified. In actual code, `transform(cur, p);` is `cur.get_to(p);` from [this json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which limits my possibilities. I gave the body to show how I use the types, not for getting advice of how not to use them there, I am sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference. Extracting the types using a type trait is still a more idiomatic and general approach that solves the problem in your question. The body of `handleRequest` is more or less irrelevant in regards to that.

Comment: If it's not clear what I mean, you would place something like `using ParamType = extract_function_type<Callback>::param_type; using ResultType = extract_function_type<Callback>::result_type;` in the function body and you have the same thing but without limiting yourself to function pointers.

Comment: @super I can't see how I can specialize a type trait on the type of a lambda since that type is unspecified. You are welcome to post a working solution.

Comment: In the older standards you can take the type of the lambdas `operator()`, since c++17 using `decltype(std::function{cb})` gives you `std::function<ReturnType(ParamType)>` which is very easy to feed to a type trait. There are plenty of solutions for that here on SO already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, implicit conversion (from lambda to function pointer) is not considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which fails deducing the template parameters.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can specify the template arguments explicitly to bypass the deduction,

```
handleRequest<XItem, ResItem>(i, [](const XItem &x) {
  return ResItem{x.val};
});
```

Or convert the lambda to function pointer explicitly,

```
handleRequest(i, static_cast<RestItem(*)(const XItem&)>([](const XItem &x) {
  return ResItem{x.val};
}));
```

Or use the `operator+` to convert the lambda to function pointer.

```
handleRequest(i, +[](const XItem &x) {
  return ResItem{x.val};
});
```

Comment: `operator+` is exactly what I was looking for since I don't need to give the types explicitly.

Comment: @flyx You might want to refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/3309790) about how `operator+` magic does. And note that only non-capture lambda could covnert to function pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Using only non-capture lambdas is perfectly viable for my use-case.